# conflict with Tkinter in Enthought-Canopy for mac

Tags: python, tkinter, enthought, canopy

I am having problems trying to compile a simple tkinter gui using Enthough-Canopy in mac. this is the code I am trying to compile:

```
from Tkinter import *
root= Tk();
root.title('Toplevel')
Label(root,text='This is the Toplevel').pack(pady=10)
root.mainloop()
```

This is the message I receive:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-
x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in 
execfile(fname, *where)
    181             else:
    182                 filename = fname
--> 183             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)
/var/folders/m1/70f55r290cz7j_sjc010k0n00000gn/T/tmp1gLNQA.py in <module>()
----> 1 from Tkinter import *
      2 
      3 root= Tk();
      4 
      5 root.title('Toplevel')
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-
x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py in <module>()
     37     # Attempt to configure Tcl/Tk without requiring PATH
     38     import FixTk
---> 39 import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
     40 tkinter = _tkinter # b/w compat for export
     41 TclError = _tkinter.TclError
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx- 
x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so, 2): Library not loaded: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/111.222.33344/lib/libtcl8.5.dylib
 Referenced from: /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-
x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so
  Reason: image not found
```

The main problem is TK or TCL, but it is already installed and working good (the code goes fine in Aptana studio 3), but when I try to run it in Canopy it fails.

Thank you for your time and support

Answer (score 2):

By default, Canopy uses a Qt4 graphical backend, which would cause problems since these two backends cannot coexist in a single process. To fix this, in the Canopy Preferences > Python tab, you can change the PyLab backend from Interactive (Qt4) to Inline (SVG) to allow the use of Tkinter.

You can either switch between these two settings depending on the project (recommended, because the default Qt backend is generally more attractive) or just specify the Inline (SVG) if you don't see the need to go back.

Comment: Hector, jweaver's answer should be correct. If true, please say so and mark the question as answered (SO protocol). Thanks!